vite (6.0.1) не работают alias
vite.config.ts
  import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
    import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
    import path from 'path';
    
    
    // Настройка резолвера с кастомными расширениями
    
    const projectRootDir = path.resolve(__dirname);
    
    export default defineConfig({
      plugins: [
        react(),
      
      ],
      resolve: {
        alias: {
          '@': path.resolve(projectRootDir, './src'),
          "app": path.resolve(projectRootDir, 'src/app/'),
          "entities": path.resolve(projectRootDir, 'src/entities'),
          "features": path.resolve(projectRootDir, 'src/features'),
          "pages": path.resolve(projectRootDir, 'src/pages'),
          "shared": path.resolve(projectRootDir, 'src/shared'),
          "widgets": path.resolve(projectRootDir, 'src/widgets'),
        },
      },
    });

tsconfig.app.json
 "baseUrl": ".",
  "paths": {
    "@/*": ["src/*"],
    "app/*": ["src/app/*"],
    "entities/*": ["src/entities/*"],
    "features/*": ["src/features/*"],
    "pages/*": ["src/pages/*"],
    "shared/*": ["src/shared/*"],
    "widgets/*": ["src/widgets/*"]
  },


Вы уверены, что там нужно использовать path.resolve?

это был один из нескольких вариантов. я разные способы использовал resolve фигурировал во множества статей  и видео что я смотрел
